# is it possible to have multiple data-option-key's set for one element

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-isotope

so i'm playing around with jquery isotope.

i have one data-option-key to filter;

```
<ul id="filters" class="option-set clearfix" data-option-key="filter">
    <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".filterA" class="selected">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".filterB">B</a></li>
</ul>
```

and i have one data-option-key to change the layout;

```
<ul id="layouts" class="option-set clearfix" data-option-key="layoutMode">
    <li><a href="#layout" data-option-value="layoutC" class="selected">C</a></li>
    <li><a href="#layout" data-option-value="layoutD">D</a></li>
</ul>
```

is there a way to combine these links, so that one  had two different data-option-keys, with different kinds of data-option-values inside. (the standard scripts i'm using can be found on the [isotope website](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/elements-complete.html))

seems pretty unlikely but its worth a shot!

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put JSON as data-option-value, therefore you can have multiple values.

```
<ul id="layouts" class="option-set clearfix" data-option-key="layoutMode">
    <li><a href="#layout" data-option-value='["one", "two"]'>C</a></li>
    <li><a href="#layout" data-option-value="layoutD">D</a></li>
</ul>​


data = $('#layouts').find('a:first').attr('data-option-value')
console.log($.parseJSON(data)[0]);​
```

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/464hh/

Comment: thank you kindly, I've never used JSON before, but it worked a charm.